# what should be the maximum size of input layer?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying to create a multilayer perceptron for an training over images dataset. images are 300*300 and input layer is 90000. Is it the right way to create it?

Comment: This is very vague, could you provide some more context about the library you are using?

Comment: library- tensorflow. Its giving this error when I am trying to run ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[90000:50000]

I am new to this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

90000 is a huge layer for what I assume you a running on a consumer-grade device. The error is likely Tensorflow running out of RAM.

If you post the whole traceback, I can be much more specific.

In general,
for a basic image classification task:

Try feeding the image into a Conv net first with dimension 300. 
Then pool to reduce spatial dimensions.